# after upgrading Google Chrome to version 63.0.3239.84 I have started receiving errors and warnings

Tags: google-chrome, dom, console, warnings

after upgrading Google Chrome to version 63.0.3239.84 I have started receiving errors and warnings in console such as:

> ```
> [DOM] Found 3 elements with non-unique id #SMTPSetting:
> [DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"):
> ```

```
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just add `autocomplete` attribute to inputs and the warnings will disappear. For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="email" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="password" required>
</div>
```

If you don't have or just don't want to set value for the attribute `autocomplete` use `autocomplete="foo"` so that warning message disappears.

More information at: https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2017/12/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html

Comment: how do I tell Chrome to shut up about it without actually changing my code to use autocomplete?

Comment: @user292701 You'll need to uncheck chrome flags in chrome://flags/, specifically under the category "Passive Event Listener Override" (chrome://flags/#passive-listener-default)

Comment: hmmm..I wouldnt have thought the two topics were related...in any event, I found this technique (back-click on specific warning) to work... https://superuser.com/questions/737390/use-the-chrome-devtools-console-filter-to-hide-console-errors-caused-by-extensio

Comment: Slightly annoyingly it still gives me the warning when I explicitly set `autocomplete="off"`. I have a field for one-off information, and autocomplete will i this case be detrimental to user experience.

Comment: Hi @Ade if you're not going to put any autocomplete just put _autocomplete="foo"_ to make the warning disappear. The value _off_ doesn't exist.

Comment: @IgnacioAra Is the W3C obsolete now? "off" used to be a value when there was only "on" or "off" and that is still listed here https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text . Also "on" and "off" are supposedly supported according to Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete but WHATWG does not list it https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill

What's the rationale for removing support for "off"?

Comment: @Ade Don't know if W3C has to update their pages but Chrome (and I suppose Mozilla also) show warnings if you set the attribute as _off_ so I found the only way to avoid them is to set another value like _foo_

Comment: @IgnacioAra I found this *very* long thread. Comment 164 explains Google's stance on it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164

Comment: @Ade Thanks for the link. They suggest us to use autocomplete and avoid _off_ or _foo_. Add atribute and an identifier for it it's the only option to forget about warnings in console...

Comment: When specifying `autocomplete="on"` the warning stays in the console. Any idea why? Based on the specs it's a valid value.

Comment: Google has apparently decided they don't care about [the W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute), or [their users opinions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466).

Answer (score 1):

They appear to have added this option recently, which hides recommendations:
-source:recommendation
in the filter box.

Found it by accident. The filter box also support auto-complete with Ctrl+Space (Windows).

Comment: Is there a syntax to hide with the filter? adding "source:recommendation" shows only the recommendations.